# Where is a free online copy of the Torah with the "correct" number of letters in it?

Tags: torah-study, hebrew, aleph-bet-letters, torah-writing

First off, my intention is to create a pretty decent replica of the Hebrew text close to the formatting of the Sefer Torah or a Tikkun, for personal documentation purposes. My question though is 2-parts.

First, about the number of characters/letters, second about where I can find a "good" copy of the Torah with this number of characters online in text format (i.e. not PDF or image).

To start, the copy of the Torah I found online is roughly **305,172** characters. I calculated this from the [original source on Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Tanakh) by only counting the Hebrew alphabet characters in [this set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block)):

```
א ב ג ד ה ו ז ח ט י ך כ ל ם מ ן נ ס ע ף פ ץ צ ק ר ש ת
```

That is, I ignored diacritics and spaces.

[This site](http://www.esofer.com/infoSeferTorah.asp) says it should be [**304,805** letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Torah). So it's off by **+367** characters. I assume that is because I took the `merged.json` data from i.e. [here](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/blob/master/json/Tanakh/Torah/Genesis/Hebrew/merged.json). Maybe it is an algorithmically merged copy of one of these?

- Tanach with Nikkud.json
- Tanach with Ta'amei Hamikra.json
- Tanach with Text Only.json (this has **316,792** letters!)
- Yehoyesh's Yiddish Tanakh Translation [yi].json

Would one of those be better? Or is there an official Torah online which has the correct number of characters? Or is there even a thing as the "correct number of characters"?

Comment: http://www.talmudology.com/jeremybrownmdgmailcom/2016/4/3/kiddushin-30a-counting-lettters try the files here? https://www.mechon-mamre.org/

Comment: @rosends [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/5483e36174b90dbd7dc4c2f7f2c1ccc9) is my analysis of the mechon-mamre.org "hebrew text only" text, which contains only **302,238** characters (without spaces). Am I supposed to include spaces and/or titles, or what is missing?

Comment: A quick look at that analysis (and I don't know exactly what I'm looking at) shows multiple words on a single line in many cases.

Comment: I cleared those out.

Comment: I saw this       "על פני\n", on line 16 but that's 2 words

Comment: [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/89e1fa5dd2b51dcb692f990330773cb5) is the postprocessing script, which normalizes/removes all whitespace.

Comment: lines 16, 21 and 27 and others still have 2 words

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100860/discussion-between-lance-pollard-and-rosends).

Comment: I can verify this, I did the same thing
The counts appear to be off I opened an issue
https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/issues/31

Comment: @Nathan Sefaria has different versions of texts. Use the one called "Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah" (which isn't the default)

Comment: I tried a similar method with [Mechon Mamre](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0.htm) and I got 304,814, but I may have made an error in removing ktiv and kri in one or more of the books. I simply copied the text and removed all the characters that didn't belong: Gen 78060 Ex 63527 Lev 44804 Num 63531 Deu 54892 Tot 304814

Comment: @DoubleAA can you link to the Sefaria source file [here](https://github.com/Sefaria/Sefaria-Export/find/master)? I am not finding anything with keyword "Miqra" in the JSON exports of the texts...